# Repeated alerts after a missed call on an Iphone

Tags: software-recommendation, notifications, vibrate, iphone

How can I get repeated alerts after a missed call on an iPhone SE?

I am looking for some way to blink the **LED flash** and **vibrate**, periodically after a call has been missed.

This periodic blinking and vibrating should continue infinitely, until I dismiss the alert.

The notification needs to be noticeable even when the phone is lying on the desk, and the screen is hidden by the flip case, so an on-screen popup is insufficient.

Decreased battery life is not a concern for me in this case. Optionally, this notification could be limited to times when the phone is connected to a charger.

Which setting or app would allow me to do this with an iPhone SE?

Something that works on an un-jailbroken phone would be greatly preferred.

---

*What I found so far:*

There is a setting for repeating message notifications, limited to at most 20 minutes after a missed message, but for some reason I was unable to find such a setting for repeating call notifications.

I also found a setting to blink the LED flash when the phone rings, but this only works for the exact moment the phone rings, it is not repeated at a later time.

Comment: It's now 2019 and you summed it up perfectly in 2016. There is still no solution. I'm a first time Iphone buyer and it shocks me that people have been complaining about this for so many years, yet they do nothing to fix this simple problem.